# How to Check to See if User Inputted a Non-Number

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this function:

```
function inputCheck()
        {
            var check = document.forms["drinkList"]["quant1"].value
            if (isNaN(check))
            {
                window.alert("Input numbers only");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I am using this code to check if the user has entered a character into a textbox. If they did, then it will display an alert saying that it only accepts numbers.
Thing is, I have 11 more text boxes I have to run this function under.

Is there anyway I can get this to work, without recreating 11 more functions?

The other textbox names are:

- quant2,
- quant3,
- quant4,
- quant5,
- whip,
- cream,
- sugar,
- chocolate,
- caramel2,

NOTE: I am also using `onchange` to make it a live check.

Comment: Identify what is variable (the input field name) and make the function accept what is variable as argument. I recommend to learn more about the basics of functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Comment: But just a little FYI  use <input type="number"> to only allow the user to enter a number .  Yes a user can edit the html and still enter other than number , but they can edit your javascirpt anyways and still pass validation .  If this is just for user experience then that will work great

Comment: I am doing this for a class assignment. This is what one of the requirements are that my professor wants. "Include a function that will run when the user enters a quantity in one of the drink or sides checkboxes. This function will check that the value entered is a number. If the value is not a number, an error message should be displayed in an alert message."

Comment: We are not here to solve your class assignments. DO IT YOURSELF as it is assigned to you..

Comment: I mean, as you see. I did do it.... but it didn't work, so I came here, to get help....logic.

Comment: What is your definition of "*only accepts numbers*"? `-2.34e-4` is a valid number.

Comment: Integers only. My professor responded to my email about the above code saying that I should make it more general by passing the value to the function as a parameter, but I am having a hard time understanding what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, didn't read clearly earlier. This should do, I guess.

```
<input onchange="inputCheck(this)">

function inputCheck(elem){
    var check = elem.value;
    if (isNaN(check))
    {
        window.alert("Input numbers only");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the built-in feature [`input type=number`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number)

However, if you really want to check it for yourself you could do something like:

```js
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function numberOnly() {

  var value = this.value;

  if (!isNumber(value)) {
    console.dir('not a number!'); // replace this with your ALERT
    this.classList.add('error');
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('error');
  }

}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.number-only'); // selects all the inputs that have the class .number-only

[].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('keyup', numberOnly); // validate the input using the numberOnly onkeyup
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
input.error {
  outline-color: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="number-only">
<input type="text" class="number-only">
<input type="text" class="number-only">
<input type="text" class="number-only">
<input type="text" class="number-only">
<input type="text" class="number-only">
```

Comment: I would love to, but that would make an alert useless. Our professor wants a popup to say that numbers are only allowed.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 oh i see! then check the new answer to see if it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to hook an event to multiple inputs is to hook an event to a *parent* (like, say, `<body>`), and check the target of the events *bubbling up*:

```
var names = ['quant2', 'quant3', 'quant4', 'quant5', 'whip', 'cream', 'sugar', 'chocolate', 'caramel2'];
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  // skip event if it was NOT triggered on a matching element
  if (names.indexOf(e.target.name) === -1) { return; }

  // code to process event...
});
```

As asides:

---

Use `<input type="number">`. This is a facility provided by the browser, it will work immediately at input-time, among other niceties (like providing a number-only keypad on mobile devices instead of a full keyboard). Here's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) and [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

why don't use jquery,it can select all textbox if add same class, example:`nonNumberTextbox`.

```
$("#drinkList .nonNumberTextbox").each(function(index, node) {
    if (isNaN(node.value)) {
        window.alert("Input numbers only");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It is forbidden to use Regular Expression in answering this question, you would get penalized, and don't ask me why

Answer (score 0):

In your code `isNaN(check)` will always return `false`. This is because the `.value` property of an `input` element always returns a string and `isNaN` of a string is `false`.

You need to coerce `check` to a number before passing it to `isNaN`. I would suggest using the [unary operator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28%29). You also need to make sure that `check` is not empty or an all white-space string because the unary plus will those will coerced them to `0`.

```
if (check.trim() === '' || isNaN(+check)) {
```

Alternatively depending on your needs you could use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` which will return `NaN` when parsing an empty or all white-space string.

```
if (isNaN(parseInt(check, 10))) { // if only integers are allowed
}

if (isNaN(parseFloat(check))) { // if integers and decimals are allowed
}
```

Yet another alternative would be to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to validate the string without coercion.

```
if(!/^\d+$/.test(check)) { // if the number needs to be an integer
}

if(!/^\d+(?:\.\d*)?$/.test(check)) { // if the number can be an integer or a decimal
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try if this works

```
var textboxes = ['quant2', 'quant3', 'quant4', 'quant5', 'whip', 'cream', 'sugar', 'chocolate', 'caramel2'];

for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++ ){
  var check = document.forms["drinkList"][textboxes[i]].value;
  if (isNaN(check)){
    window.alert("Input numbers only");
    break;
  }
}
```